# Converting data from yyyyMM to yyyyQQ

Tags: r, date, time

My date data is in the format "yyyymm", specifically 20071 / 20074 / 20077 / 200710.

I want to convert this to quarters.

Also, in another dataset I have monthly data that I want to aggregate to quarters. Is there a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `yearqtr` class repesents a year and quarter internally as a year plus a fraction (0 for Q1, 1/4 for Q2, 2/4 for Q3 and 3/4 for Q4) and displays as shown:

```
library(zoo)
ym <- c(20071, 20074, 20077, 200710) # test data

yq <- as.yearqtr(as.character(ym), "%Y%m")
yq
## [1] "2007 Q1" "2007 Q2" "2007 Q3" "2007 Q4"
```

It is probably preferable to leave it as `yearqtr` since you can perform many operations on it (e.g. `yq + 1/4` is the next quarter) but if you want it as pure character strings use `format(yq)` or `as.character(yq)`.

Comment: what if my date is in the format 33653? how to i turn it into a date and then to quarters?

Comment: Is that a Windows Excel date? If so `as.Date("1899-12-30") + 33653` will convert it to a `Date` class object and `as.yearqtr` will convert that to a year and quarter.  See R News 4/1 Help Desk article starting on page 29 for more info.   https://www.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you could append a temporary date and extract year and quarter from it.

```
x <- as.character(c(20071, 20074, 20077, 200710))
temp <- as.Date(paste(x, "01"), "%Y%m %d")
paste(format(temp, "%Y"), quarters(temp))
#[1] "2007 Q1" "2007 Q2" "2007 Q3" "2007 Q4"
```

If you want quarter as numbers, we can use `lubridate::quarter`

```
paste(format(temp, "%Y"), lubridate::quarter(temp))
#[1] "2007 1" "2007 2" "2007 3" "2007 4"
```